# app.post is not working in express.js

Tags: express

I have been working on express.js lately for the first time and i am facing this issue.Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var option = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    },
    replset: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    }
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/person', option).then(function(){
    console.log("sucess");
}, function(err) {
    console.log("error");
});


var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   age: Number,
   nationality: String
});
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// for parsing application/xwww-
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//form-urlencoded

// for parsing multipart/form-data
//app.use(upload.array());
//app.use(express.static('./public'));

// app.post('/', function(req, res){
//    console.log(req.body);
//    res.send("recieved your request!");
// });
app.get('/person', function(req, res){
  console.log("in gettttttttttttttt")
   res.render('person');
});
app.post('/person', function(req, res){
  console.log("in post");
   var personInfo = req.body; //Get the parsed information
   if(!personInfo.name || !personInfo.age || !personInfo.nationality){
      res.render('show_message', {
         message: "Sorry, you provided worng info", type: "error"});
   } else {
      var newPerson = new Person({
         name: personInfo.name,
         age: personInfo.age,
         nationality: personInfo.nationality
      });

      newPerson.save(function(err, Person){
         if(err)
            res.render('show_message', {message: "Database error", type: "error"});
         else
            res.render('show_message', {
               message: "New person added", type: "success", person: personInfo});
      });
   }
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Get call successfully renders the form on UI but when i submit the form,post does not work.
Here is the pug form file

```
  html
head
   title Person
   body
      form(action = "/person", method = "POST")
      div
         label(for = "name") Name:
         input(name = "name")
      br
      div
         label(for = "age") Age:
         input(name = "age")
      br
      div
         label(for = "nationality") Nationality:
         input(name = "nationality")
      br
      button(type = "submit") Create new person
```

Connection to mongodb is successful.

console does not show any error in debug mode when i hit submit button.
Please guide!!

Comment: is this `console.log("in post");` showing?

Comment: no and no activity in network tab of chrome when i hit submit

Comment: then the problem is in the frontend. Make a POST with postman and you will surely see the console log

Comment: its working now button was flowing out of form.MAde changes in pug